# Which MinGW version for QT 5.02?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I am using QT 5.02 for a university project and I need the correct MinGw version to use g++ as my compiler. So far every version I tried did not work, I downloaded it and manually added it in the compiler settings but I could not select it in the kit settings (which is a sign of incompatibility I believe). So which version is the right one?

Comment: Recent MinGW versions should all work, 4.9.x and later, maybe even previous versions, as far back as 4.7.x, this version of Qt is from 2013 after all. You are probably not doing something right. I suggest you install MinGW through the Qt installer, this way you are guaranteed to get a good installation that will work with Qt.

Comment: 32/64 bit version? Can't you use a more recent version of Qt5? Current is Qt5.5.0 to date. Here is a [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/files/qt/x86-64/5.5.0/mingw-5.1/seh/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0.exe/download) to a working set for Windows (64-bit processors) and x86 (32-bit) versions get shipped by Digia packed with a working compiler.

Comment: @FabriceNicol - actually 5.5.1 was released recently.